# Mobius strip algebraic properties.

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, projective-geometry

I just was thinking about mobius strip, and asked myself simple questions, which I could not convince myself of answers and hope someone can give my a concrete answer.

I know Mobius strip is a line bundle over the circle as  real manifolds, but how this transfer to algebraic geometry.

Q1- What algebro-geometric properties of analogous Mobius strip in algebraic geometry? i.e. is it a variety, or some sort of a general scheme?

in case the above answer to  Q1 is yes please see Q2 , otherwise thanks.

2-how it's constructed in this respect?
i,e. if it's any of the above, any informain about its structure sheaf if it's a scheme, or coordinate ring in case it's  a variety?

UPDATE:
After the discussion bellow with kenny Wong, I realized that the rightwo question is this:
1- Can we have a mobuis strip analogy as a complex manifold, I mean will it look the same band that twisted around the edges and glued?

I appreciate your help here, thank you.

Comment: Is your Mobius strip a $[0,1]$ bundle over $S^1$, with the obvious twist in the $[0,1]$ as you go around the circle? This most certainly isn't an algebraic variety, as far as I can tell! Neither is $[0,1]$ or $S^1$, for that matter!

Comment: If I understood you right, yes my bundle is the twist around the circle, but why did you say $S^1$ is not algebric, I think it's $\spec \C[x,y]/<x^2+y^2-1>$ isn't it?

Comment: ${\rm Spec \ }\mathbb C [x,y]/(x^2 + y^2 - 1)$ is defined over the complex numbers. $S^1$ is defined over the reals.

Comment: Thank you so much. so I see now. Can mobuis strip be defined over the circle $${\rm Spec \ }\mathbb C [x,y]/(x^2 + y^2 - 1)$ ? is there an analogy here?. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You might try defining a complex line bundle over this variety. Though I have a feeling that any such line bundle might be trivial in the complex algebraic category - I'm not sure.

Comment: In fact, unless I'm terribly mistaken, any line bundle on this variety is trivial because the variety is smooth and any divisor on this variety is linearly equivalent to the zero divisor.

Comment: So let's assume it's true that it is trivial, which I will try to prove, what would be the picture of this mobuis strip, I might be naively having a wrong picture, but would the mobuis strip be just a sort of a a cylinder? like ${\rm Spec \ }\mathbb C [x,y]/(x^2 + y^2 - 1)\times \math C$ ? I mean we don't have a mobuis strip anymore if we go to the category of complex, am I right?

Comment: Dear user93893 and commenters:  the Möbius bundle  is a perfectly legitimate real  algebraic, non trivial line bundle on the real circle. There is no need to mention $\mathbb C$ in this question, which only confuses the issue. See my answer.

Comment: No offense to anyone, but why this question is closed as unclear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Möbius strip is a perfectly valid algebraic line bundle bundle on the real circle , which is the perfectly valid real algebraic variety $$S=\operatorname {Proj}\mathbb R[X,Y]=\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb R}$$ We can look at the circle  also as the subscheme $S^1=V(X^2+Y^2-1)\subset \mathbb A^2_\mathbb R$, i.e. $$S^1=\operatorname {Spec}\frac {\mathbb R[X,Y]}{\langle X^2+Y^2-1\rangle}=:\operatorname {Spec}\mathbb R[x,y]$$ Hence the real circle is both an affine and a projective variety, which is of course only possible because $\mathbb R$ is not algebraically closed!

**Over $S$**
 The Möbius bundle is  the total space of the tautological line bundle $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb R}}(-1)$.

**Over $S^1$**
In the second incarnation $S^1$ of the circle, the Möbius bundle is the line bundle  associated to the ideal $\langle y,x-1\rangle\subset \mathbb R[x,y]$, which is a non free projective module of rank one over the ring $\mathbb R[x,y]$.
In other words the Möbius bundle is the line bundle associated to the divisor $1.P$ of the circle, where $P$ is the closed point with coordinates $(1,0)$.

Comment: Thank you so much. very elegant and clear answer.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words, dear user93893.